# How can I permanently change the default user agent in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, chromium, user-agent

In edge, I can change the default user agent in Chrome. I can do the following right now:

1. In Edge, select More Tools->Developer Tools.
2. In the developer toolbar select More Tools->Network Condition. Note that this is not the same more tools as the last step, that one is on the edge toolbar, this is on the developer toolbar.
3. On the bottom pane, uncheck use browser default and then add your custom user agent.

However, if you close the browser, the settings goes away. I need to settings retained. If not, a way to change the default user agent would work, too. Reigstry editing is ok.

Note that I cannot use a extension like switch user agent. When I click on a shortcut, it launches Edge to go to a site and the site sees the user agent and changes the UI accordingly. If I click on the shortcut the site is open before the extension changes the user agent, so I need this to occur before the extension activates.

Comment: I don't use Edge but as it's based on Chromium, Chromium's switch might work. If it does then when starting Edge pass this argument via command line: `-user-agent="Foo"` where `Foo` is the string of your choice

Comment: Hmm.. not super-sure what the issue is. If I run start msedge --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (SMART-TV; Linux; Tizen 4.0.0.2) AppleWebkit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/9.2 TV Safari/605.1.15" "https://www.youtube.com/tv#/" It doesn't go into the tv mode, but if I tried it from the browser itself, it works. Will probably need to look at the network logs.

Comment: I tested and found that the user agent is changed in Edge. But it seems that when the site loads, the user agent is override again. I also made test in [Edge Canary (Version 93.0.931.0)](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/canary) which version is higher than Edge (Version 91.0.864.54), it works with `--user-agent` override. So I think the issue will be fixed in future version of Edge, and you can wait for the release of newer version.